# Typical SharePoint On Premise Setup/Authentication Providers

Tags: sharepoint-server, csom, web-application-zones

I was wondering if anyone could advise me on the following.

I've currently been working on an application and using CSOM to get information/data from SharePoint. This works without any problems using Network Credentials to authenticate and the web application has the following enabled
 [image]

In a typical scenario or company setup will this be enabled on for example My Sites/OneDrive and Team Sites? Would this be enabled for users say on the company domain/network and if needed to be accessed off the company network extended into the extranet zone with Forms authentication.

One test case I have come across is that I have setup a web application with just Forms based authentication. The provider being AD/LDAP. Currently this would not work with my application as I'm using Network credentials.

I was looking to advise users to extend the application with 'Integrated WIndows Authentication' so this application can read data etc.

Any advice is much appreciated and thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

To answer your question from my experience, yes most companies opt for Windows Auth with NTLM. Some opt for Kerberos (and I steer them that way), which is faster/more secure. Others yet will go the SAML route, but that's on the rarer side of implementations.

You can have multiple authentication providers without extending a Web Application. And in fact, the Default Zone must have WIA enabled for Search.

Comment: Thanks, when you say you can have multiple authentication providers. I think I did test this. I had forms and WIA enabled. This would then give the a user an option to choose between Windows or forms is this correct? If so, does this often happen? I'm not familiar with 'typical setups' with in a company